Warnings on CSS file when adding the tailwind imports
screenshot of the wranings
Are these warnings a normal thing when using tailwind in an html + css app only or there is any way that i can make it go away???
I don't really know what to try i don't want to mess up the project cause i'm new to this.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/175554 please enter the details of the error into question

It's a warning from VSCode, not explicitly an error. It warns about this because VSCode's built-in CSS parser does not "know" about Tailwind syntax. Tailwind should still work regardless. If you really want to get rid of the error though, you could do one of:

Use the PostCSS plugin
Use the Tailwind intelliSense plugin
Turn off CSS validation

